# gitkraken push failed because of ssh

Tags: ssh, version-control, gitkraken

I'm getting this error:

```
Push Failed: SSH could not write data: Unable to send channel data
```

I think my `ssh bitbucket key` is fine because it works with other repos.

Please help.

Comment: Same here. My GitKraken seems to be a bit lazier though. The push doesn't work (keeps loading) and no error is displayed. Really frustrating.

Comment: I have this kind of issue on multiple GitHub repositories. It happens every few months. I also use GitKraken but I've found that I can't push using GitHub Desktop either. To resolve it I typically clone the original repository then copy in my changed files. Then I can push my changes and everything will be fine for some months after that. I've tried a lot of other things, like reauthenticating to GitHub, creating a new cert for GitHub, etc. and none of it worked.

Comment: One thing I've found in the past that sometimes works. I'll roll back my local commit but keep the changed files. Then I add a subset of those files to the commit and push it. Then a few more files and push. I can break it up into 2 or 3 commits and pushes and it works. Note, these are just source code so they are small, I'm not pushing big files at all in these repos. This technique doesn't always work though.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue, below cause & resolution.

Cause: I had a commit with a large file in it ~200MB. I believe remote push was hitting a timeout limit or something & GitKraken throws this error.

Resolution: I pushed the commits using native git client (Git Bash). It took ~1 hour to push the commits to remote. Once that commit was out of the way, I'm now able to push to remote without trouble from GitKraken.

Moral of the story, don't use git for large files, Git LFS is a better answer.

Comment: But I only have java classes to push. Any help from this ?